# Как перезапустить Apache?

Tags: apache

Установил, ранее работал, теперь не хочет запускаться. Из за него не могу запустить сайт.
Что делать?

Comment: @Чингиз Бостанов Не забывайте принимать ответы (галочка).

Comment: Товарищи, а чего вы гадаете?  
Логи работы запуска апача в студию!

Comment: Если не знаешь где логи и как их посмотреть, то хотя бы ОС нужно указать. Да и вообще, ОС всегда нужно указывать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Вспомнить, какие изменения были внесены в систему с момента последнего запуска апача. Среди них могут быть те, которые сломали апач.
2. Посмотреть ошибки, которые апач сообщает при запуске.
3. Посмотреть логи апача, которые выводятся по путям, прописанным в директивах ErrorLog и CustomLog.

Comment: Вообщем вот что я делал я удалил PHP и поставил Adobe Dreamweaver 
и все-это могло повлиять?

Comment: При зпуске пишет Busy...потом Apache service  started

Comment: Если сайт использует PHP, то удаление PHP однозначно помешает работе апача. :)

Comment: Как вы думаете, если начать все с начала? У меня стоит xampp (посоветовали).

Comment: Если сервер тестовый и реальной посещаемости нет, проще - сначала.

Comment: А, ну все, тогда спасибо. )

Answer (score 1):

Для начала запустите httpd.exe -t

Comment: Да, спасибо! Решил проблему методом дедукции. Проблема была -пропущенная строка в httpd.conf.

Comment: С помощью этой команды это бы сразу выяснилось.